# need to add counter value in name attribute of each element of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

my code is working but I don't what sort of counter value it has been concatenating

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $("#addNew").click(function() {
        var maindiv = document.getElementById('nestedFeilds').innerHTML;
        $("#showhere").append(maindiv);
        $("#showhere :input").each(function(){
            var orignalname = $(this).attr('name');
            $(this).attr('name', orignalname + i); 
             i++;
        });
    });
});
```

I want same counter value for every element in div when click event fire and then second incremented counter value for every element in same div but now it in increasing counter value in every element

this is the div which I am cloning

```
<div class=class="col-md-8 col-xs-8  verticalLine" id="nestedFeilds"  style=" margin-left: 10px ;float:left; display: none">
    <a href="" style="color: red;margin-left: auto; ">Delete Education</a>
    <input  type="text" placeholder="School Name" class="form-control" id="School_Name"  required="" name="School_Name">
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Feild of Study" class="form-control" id="feild_Name"  required="" name="feild_Name">
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Degree" class="form-control" id="Degree_Name"  required="" name="Degree_Name">
    <br>
    <div class ="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" id="YearName"  style="float:left;" required="" name="first_year_name" value=''>
                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                <option value="2007">2007</option>
                <option value="2006">2006</option>
                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                <option value="2004">2004</option>
                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                <option value="1990">1990</option>
                <option value="1989">1989</option>
                <option value="1988">1988</option>
                <option value="1987">1987</option>
                <option value="1986">1986</option>
                <option value="1985">1985</option>
                <option value="1984">1984</option>
                <option value="1983">1983</option>
                <option value="1982">1982</option>
                <option value="1981">1981</option>
                <option value="1980">1980</option>
                <option value="1979">1979</option>
                <option value="1978">1978</option>
                <option value="1977">1977</option>
                <option value="1976">1976</option>
                <option value="1975">1975</option>
                <option value="1974">1974</option>
                <option value="1973">1973</option>
                <option value="1972">1972</option>
                <option value="1971">1971</option>
                <option value="1970">1970</option>
                <option value="1969">1969</option>
                <option value="1968">1968</option>
                <option value="1967">1967</option>
                <option value="1966">1966</option>
                <option value="1965">1965</option>
                <option value="1964">1964</option>
                <option value="1963">1963</option>
                <option value="1962">1962</option>
                <option value="1961">1961</option>
                <option value="1960">1960</option>
                <option value="1959">1959</option>
                <option value="1958">1958</option>
                <option value="1957">1957</option>
                <option value="1956">1956</option>
                <option value="1955">1955</option>
                <option value="1954">1954</option>
                <option value="1953">1953</option>
                <option value="1952">1952</option>
                <option value="1951">1951</option>
                <option value="1950">1950</option>
                <option value="1949">1949</option>
                <option value="1948">1948</option>
                <option value="1947">1947</option>  
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" style="margin-left: -20px; float:left;"  id="monthName"  required="" name="first_Name_month" value=''>Select Month

            <option value='01'>January</option>
            <option value='02'>February</option>
            <option value='03'>March</option>
            <option value='04'>April</option>
            <option value='05'>May</option>
            <option value='06'>June</option>
            <option value='07'>July</option>
            <option value='08'>August</option>
            <option value='09'>September</option>
            <option value='10'>October</option>
            <option value='11'>November</option>
            <option value='12'>December</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: -20px;float:left;">
        <p style="text-align: left; margin-top: 5px">&nbsp;to</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" id="YearName" style="margin-right:30px; float:left;"  required="" name="second_year_name" value=''>Select Month

            <option value="2017">2017</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                <option value="2007">2007</option>
                <option value="2006">2006</option>
                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                <option value="2004">2004</option>
                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                <option value="1990">1990</option>
                <option value="1989">1989</option>
                <option value="1988">1988</option>
                <option value="1987">1987</option>
                <option value="1986">1986</option>
                <option value="1985">1985</option>
                <option value="1984">1984</option>
                <option value="1983">1983</option>
                <option value="1982">1982</option>
                <option value="1981">1981</option>
                <option value="1980">1980</option>
                <option value="1979">1979</option>
                <option value="1978">1978</option>
                <option value="1977">1977</option>
                <option value="1976">1976</option>
                <option value="1975">1975</option>
                <option value="1974">1974</option>
                <option value="1973">1973</option>
                <option value="1972">1972</option>
                <option value="1971">1971</option>
                <option value="1970">1970</option>
                <option value="1969">1969</option>
                <option value="1968">1968</option>
                <option value="1967">1967</option>
                <option value="1966">1966</option>
                <option value="1965">1965</option>
                <option value="1964">1964</option>
                <option value="1963">1963</option>
                <option value="1962">1962</option>
                <option value="1961">1961</option>
                <option value="1960">1960</option>
                <option value="1959">1959</option>
                <option value="1958">1958</option>
                <option value="1957">1957</option>
                <option value="1956">1956</option>
                <option value="1955">1955</option>
                <option value="1954">1954</option>
                <option value="1953">1953</option>
                <option value="1952">1952</option>
                <option value="1951">1951</option>
                <option value="1950">1950</option>
                <option value="1949">1949</option>
                <option value="1948">1948</option>
                <option value="1947">1947</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" id="monthName"  style="float:left; margin-left: -20px;"   required="" name="Second__Name_month" value=''>Select Month

            <option value='01'>January</option>
            <option value='02'>February</option>
            <option value='03'>March</option>
            <option value='04'>April</option>
            <option value='05'>May</option>
            <option value='06'>June</option>
            <option value='07'>July</option>
            <option value='08'>August</option>
            <option value='09'>September</option>
            <option value='10'>October</option>
            <option value='11'>November</option>
            <option value='12'>December</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share your html as well

Comment: sir I have provide that

Comment: Do you mean that value of `i` is not reset to zero on next click ?

Comment: no I don't want to be reset it should be increase

Comment: instead of incrementing count use `[]` or each input+select-box like `School_Name[],feild_Name[]`,..... so on

Comment: but it is increasing in every element of dive I want one counter value in every element of div and on next click when new div append it should be increase by one and concatenate to every element of div

Comment: @AlivetoDie so how it can make my input element different on posting

Comment: when you will post it will create array with indexes like 0,1,2.... so easy to distinguish and use

Comment: and what should I change in jquery

Comment: just remove this code `$("#showhere :input").each(function(){
            var orignalname = $(this).attr('name');
            $(this).attr('name', orignalname + i); 
             i++;
        });`

Comment: but @AlivetoDie I also want to delete that div if I dnt diffentiate with counter how can I delete

Comment: each div have delete button?yes then on click of button delete it's parent div.that's it

Comment: $("#showhere > a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('#2ndmainContainer').remove();
    });

Comment: sorry to bother but it is not deleting